# An existing Contact could not found with the id 'XXXX'. Confirm both the object type and id are correct

Tags: workbench

If I try to navigate to any contact like this:
https://workbench.developerforce.com/retrieve.php?id=XXXXX

I get the error:
An existing Contact could not found with the id 'XXXX'. Confirm both the object type and id are correct.

I can view the contact just fine in Salesforce.

Navigating with the retrieve.php url works for other objects like opportunities.
Is there perhaps an add-on module that is causing this to fail. I saw this error in the past and it was because my user did not have a license for an add-on.

Any way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I never knew, you could fetch details that way. However, I tried it and it just works fine.  But - is there any specific reason why are you trying to retrieve a record detail this way? However, you may like to review that the Id you are using in the request is correct, because if I changed a character in the Id that I used for this test, resulted in the error that you got.

Comment: @JayantDas RE: reason. It gives me that page with all the fields and their values in a nice two-column table. I don't know of another way without specifying all the fields in the SOQL input.

Comment: Yeah, that's really a cool way to retrieve and view the details. However it still works for me, most likely has to do with something going around in your scenario.